# What is the correct way of using razor page c# variables in javasript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

Right now I display the c# variables that I need into invisible HTML spans. Then I grab them in javascript using jQuery.

I have only had to use it with relatively small amounts of information, like a small array of group codes and 1 or 2 integers.
Is this the correct way of doing so? Or should I make JSON API's for those variables?

Comment: There's no one 'right way' to do this. It depends entirely on the use case.

Comment: Why not just add `var myIntVar = @Model.Property;` inside a `<script>` block?

Comment: Why spans? I think you could do it in `script` elements, then it'd be visible in JS :)

Comment: Because I did not know this was possible :)
If I add it to a script element, will it be visible in an external javascript file?
Say I have a c# `string Name` in **dashboard.cshtml**, and I add it to an `script` element. How do I make it availaible in **dashboard.js**

Comment: If dashboard.js is added in dashboard.cshtml, it will be accessible. Make sure the variable declaration runs before it is accessed in the external file

Comment: @adiga Thanks, it should be `var myIntVar = '@Model.Property'` though, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Quotes are required for string properties, not numbers. Since you mentioned integers, I skipped that part. Through cshtml, you are basically creating an HTML file. If the Model.Property is say, `"Omar"`, it will translate to `var myIntVar = Omar`. So, when it runs on the browser, it will look for a `Omar` identifier.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks once again